# Is there a way to query the internal state store generated by kafka streams?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka-streams

I have joined two kakfa streams using .joinWindows function , after which Two changelog topics are generted

- {consumer-group}--KSTREAM-JOINOTHER-0000000005-store-changelog
- {consumer-group}--KSTREAM-JOINTHIS-0000000004-store-changelog

1.what is the purpose of each of the two topics?

2.What is the data stored by them, is it a key-value pair ?

3.Is there a way to query these internal topic and get the number of events present in these internal topics ?

Could pass the internal store to a processor and then accessing it tried using windowstore, but it doesn’t have a function to get number of events processed.
code :

```
Keyvalue stateStore = processorContext.getStateStore("KSTREAM-JOINTHIS-0000000005-store");
stateStore.approximateNumEntries();
```

```
org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractReadWriteDecorator$WindowStoreReadWriteDecorator cannot be cast to class org.apache.kafka.streams.state.KeyValueStore
```

I want to get the total count of events entering the stream across various partitions and the the number of joins that took place

Answer (score 0):

> 1.what is the purpose of each of the two topics?

Those are the changelog topics that back the states stores involved in the join.  Each "side" of the join will look in the other side's state store for a match on a key, i.e., perform a join.

> 2.What is the data stored by them? Is it a key-value pair?

Yes, changelog topics are Kafka topics, and they store the key-value pairs in the state stores for durability.

> 3.Is there a way to query these internal topic and get the number of events present in these internal topics ?

You could point a consumer at those topics to inspect the records.  But what is the use case for doing so? Also, you'd want to ensure you never produce records to those topics.

The state stores for joins aren't accessible via interactive queries.  If you want to get an idea of the number of joins, you could add an operator after the join that logs a running counter and logs the results or something similar.